# How do you deploy a MEEN stack webapp as opposed to a MEAN one?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, express, ember.js

I created a simple portfolio website using mongo, express, ember, node, sass, and bootstrap. So far I have a local mongo instance running and my local ember production version working fine on my laptop but I have no idea how to make my site available online.

I've been searching and there's lots of tutorials of how to deploy a MEAN stack app, but not a MEEN stack app.

So, what are the differences between these two stacks in deployment steps?

I was thinking of deploying to either amazon web services, digital ocean (both which I have student pack discounts for), or GoDaddy (which I have a free domain name from). Which should I choose (from deployment possibility standpoint) and what steps do I take to deploy it from its current state (production mode)?

Comment: Any tutorial for deploying a MEAN stack app should work fine for your MEEN stack since the only difference in those stacks is Angular vs Ember and those run in the browser, not on the server.

Comment: @MarkB I rephrased the Q to not sound like a tutorial/recommendation request so guess you can upgrade this to an answer.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I'm not sure I agree with your edit, and the question still includes a request for a recommendation of a hosting service, which still makes the question off topic.

Comment: @MarkB "from deployment possibility standpoint", it's quite objective and is most likely "all three support this". You are free to ignore this part anyway (or explicitly state you're refusing to deal with it) as it's a side question.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I find it to be a bad idea to give answers to off-topic questions. Especially questions I've voted to close. It encourages other bad questions.

Comment: @MarkB And you already answered it. Well, whatever.

Comment: thanks @MarkB, that first comment helped. And sorry for making the unclear post/second irrelevant question. this is my first time posting on stackoverflow.

Comment: If you could point me in the direction of how you got all 4 to work together please show me the way. I have been racking my brain on finding a tutorial for making exactly what you made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used all three providers. I would recommend digital ocean's one click deploy droplets if you want to hit the ground running quickly. Digital Ocean's community has tutorials for nearly all basic use cases you'd want to emulate when deploying an application.